In non-linear optics, how does the resulting polarisation of SHG generate an electric field of new properties?
When a high electric field is applied to a non-linear medium it creates a polarisation via:
${P}=\epsilon_{0}{\chi}^{(1)}{E}$, where ${E}$ is the total electric field. Does the induced electric field then have a amplitude of ${E}={P}/\epsilon_{0}{\chi}^{(1)}$? If so, does this not become a circular process which dampens in amplitude over time?

Your question is unclear, you start by asking about a nonlinear medium and then talk about linear optics (linear relation between P and E means linear optics). About your question, because it is about linear optics, there are plenty of sources giving great explanations about what's happening. You should really look at this wonderful video from 3b1b: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTzGBJPuJwM

As mentioned by Ofek, what you wrote is a linear process. Regardless, to find the induced electric field you need to solve the EM wave-equation using the polarisation density $P$ as a source term.
